# Is there an ILDASM tool for dotnet 5 or 6?

Tags: .net-core, ildasm

The dotnet sdks for the "core" versions apparently have no ildasm tool. While the old Ildasm tool that shipped with dotnet 48 works with dotnet 6 assemblies I wonder if there is an Ildasm for dotnet 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ilasm` and `ildasm` are available as nuget packages on nuget.org. Look for `runtime.{RUNTIME_ID}.Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm` and `runtime.{RUNTIME_ID}.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm` packages.

For example:

- Linux x64: https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm/
- macOS arm64: https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.osx-arm64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm/
- Windows x64: https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm/

These contain executibles built for each specific .NET (and .NET Core) version for each platform.