# Why is Ildasm for dotnet 7 installed with Visual Studio 2022 in a folder named NETFX 4.8?

Tags: .net, ildasm

Why is the latest ildasm version that ships with dotnet 7 in a folder named "NETFX 4.8"?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ildasm.exe
```

I searched long for the latest Ildasm until I realized that the NETFX 4.8 works for dotnet core 7.

Related but different question:
[Is there an ILDASM tool for dotnet 5 or 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825106/is-there-an-ildasm-tool-for-dotnet-5-or-6)

Comment: It is not the latest, distribution is now done through [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm/7.0.0).  But sure, the old one works just fine since the internal format of assemblies did not change in the past 13 years.

Comment: i realized the nuget packaging but in my head nuget is just for libraries, i shift my mind that it also delivers tools. thx, that perfectly answers my question. feel free to "package" it as answer ;)